# I need assistance with cog_command_error

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm new to using cogs and have just found out about cog_command_error. I have attempted to apply it to my code

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        """Reports errors to users"""
        m, s = divmod(error.retry_after, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRole):
            await ctx.send("You do not have the correct role for this command.")
        elif isinstance(error,commands.errors.CheckFailure):
            await ctx.send("This command is blocked from this channel please use it in <#597918255188803588>")
        elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            errMessage = f"{ctx.author.mention}, Try again in {round(h)} hours, {round(m)} minutes, and {round(s)} seconds."
            await ctx.send(errMessage)
```

however i keep getting this error :

```
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 596, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\GovsM\cogs\fun.py", line 19, in <module>
    class fun(commands.Cog):
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\cog.py", line 124, in __new__
    raise TypeError(no_bot_cog.format(base, elem))
TypeError: Commands or listeners must not start with cog_ or bot_ (in method fun.cog_command_error)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jimmy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 48, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Jimmy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Jimmy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\GovsM\Govs.py", line 438, in <module>
    loadall()
  File "c:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\GovsM\Govs.py", line 436, in loadall
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 653, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 599, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.fun' raised an error: TypeError: Commands or listeners must not start with cog_ or bot_ (in method fun.cog_command_error)
```

I would appreciate any assistance in working out what's wrong, I've tried multiple ways and the only way I got it working was on on_command_error which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the decorator. It should just be `async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):` with no decorator.

Here is a small example where if you pass in a string as the argument it print "Bad argument error" to console

```
@commands.command()
async def numError(self, ctx, test: int):
    await ctx.send(test)

async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        print("Bad Argument Error")
```

Comment: I removed:   @commands.Cog.listener() and now its not sending the message to discord but instead to Terminal, it says: discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The check functions for command Bird failed."

Comment: This is the Cog https://paste.pythondiscord.com/omizicafom.py

Comment: @Exile The issue is `m, s = divmod(error.retry_after, 60)` line because CheckFailure errors don't have a retry_after field. You need to move those two lines of code down in the `elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):` block.